# How to enable "sa" account in SQL Server 2019 Express after login with Windows Authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have installed SQL Server Express 2019 on my machine and after installation, I am able to login into server using the Windows Authentication method like

[image]

And as you can see the `sa` account has been disabled by default

[image]

So I tried to enable the `sa` account like

[image]

But I am getting this error message

[image]

> Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error:15151)

Even when I tried to change the server authentication mode from Windows Authentication Mode to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode at

[image]

I am facing this error:

[image]

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error; 229)

So it looks like I have no/not granted any permission to do any anything! when login with Windows which apparently is my only option to get into server!(this is also happening when I tried to create new user!)

How can I get this to act as an administrator for DB when I login?

I have already seen and tried [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220586/cant-change-authentication-mode-from-windows-to-both-sql-server-and-windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is poor practice in the first place. If you need a local admin account you should create a different login such that attackers and automated tools won't be able to just assume the user name.

But remember: I said, "If". You can get admin/sa rights to administer the server (or create your initial local login) by logging into the computer (not the database) with the local `administrator` account. Then you can use using Windows Authentication from that account to access the database server as a server administrator.